# In Ember, how do I set a specific object which is part of an array in a controller?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ember.js

I am not sure if this has been answered before, but I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow related to this. I have the following question.

I have an object (obj) and an array of obj (objArray) which is defined as follows:

```
  obj: {a: 1, b:2}
  objArray:[]
```

Firstly, how do I set the value of objArray such that it can be set as an array of obj? Currently I am doing it using the following method:

```
  for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
      objArray[i] = obj;
  }
```

Is there a  better way to set the values of the array?

Also, I would like to be able to set individual parameter values of the objects in the array using a function similar to the following:

```
  setA : function (id, a) {

     this.get('objArray')[id].a = a; // this is not working. I get the error " You must use Ember.set() to access this property (of [object Object]) "
     this.get('objArray')[id].set('a', a); // this also does not work. I get the error "Object has no method set"
  }
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem? I apologise if this is a silly question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `objectAt()`, i.e. `this.get('objArray').objectAt(id).set('a', a)`. However, please note that the variable `id` is not actually an identifier, but an *index*, so you might want to consider renaming it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I figured out if I have to use .objectAt(id) , I have to define the object differently. Hence instead of defining it as "objArray[i] = obj ", I have to define it as objArray.addObject(Ember.Object.create({a: 1, b:2})) . Then I can use your method of  this.get('objArray').objectAt(id).set('a', a) . Thanks for your help!